# Обращение с использованием глагола в 1 лице множественного числа

Tags: выбор-слов, этикет

Я с ужасом замечаю, как чаще и чаще ко мне обращаются во множественном числе.
К примеру: ***"Девушка, проходим, не стоим!"***
Мне сильно режет слух и я осознаю, что сама могу так обращаться только к ребенку:
***"А что мы сегодня кушали?"***

Считаю такое обращение оскорбительным и хамским, но, к сожалению, не могу ничем это подкрепить: где найти по данному вопросу какие-нибудь правила?
Товарищи лингвисты и филологи, выручайте!

Answer (score 2):

В действительности, это форма изъявительного наклонения используется в значении повелительного наклонения вместо более вежливого "девушка, проходите, не стойте".

Такое обращение  более категорично, но все-таки лучше, чем, к примеру, следующее: "Девушка, а ну быстро прошла вперед".

Answer (score 1):

К Вам обращаются в единственном числе. Девушка - вот обращение, которое стоит в единственном числе. Глагол проходить в 1 лице множественного числа значит совместное действие говорящего с кем-либо. "Мы сегодня играем в такую замечательную игру, как в Монополию". Если это предложение говорю я, то это означает, что я играю с кем-то. То есть местоимением 1 лица множественного числа (мы) указывает, что действие выполняется говорящим и еще кем-то.

Что касается этого обращения, то оно часто используется в разговорном стиле.

Answer (score 1):

В экспрессивной речи возможно употребление 1-го лица множественного числа вместо 2-го лица: Ну, как мы себя чувствуем? Что скажете хорошенького? (Ч.). Так называемая "форма вежливости" выражается употреблением формы 2-го лица множественного числа вместо формы 2-го лица единственного числа.

Подробнее можно прочитать на Грамма.ру. http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=2.28

Это не повелительное наклонение. Но мн.ч. вместо ед.ч. в повелительным наклонение звучит более вежливо и не ставит акцент на сам приказ. Ср.напр: Девушка, выходите! Согласитесь, звучит более категорично, чем аналогичное обращение во мн.ч.

Comment: Как мы себя чувствуем - это вежливая фамильярность, уместная в определенных ситуациях. Но это не повелительное наклонение, как в приведенном примере.

Comment: Правильно: "Девушка, выходите, пожалуйста". "Девушка, выходим" - это, может быть, не категорично, но фамильярно, на что и сетует автор вопроса. (Серж, почему Вы отвечаете не в комментарии, а на поле ответа).

Comment: Я уже и сам запутался, где отвечать, а где нет.

Comment: Это ваше поле, но когда идет диалог, то удобно писать в комментариях, иначе ваши новые реплики сложно отделить от текста основного ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Такое обращение используется тогда, когда обращающийся не желает обращаться к вам на "вы", а тыкать нельзя. По каким-то причинам он хочет показать свое превосходство над вами и именно поэтому не хочет проявлять уважение к вам, пытаясь вас принизить.  Например, представителям власти и чиновникам нельзя тыкать и хамить открыто, вот и был ими найден такой способ узаконенного хамства. Такое обращение унизительно и отвратительно, а также показывает невысокий уровень интеллектуального развития обращающегося. Как доказательство: полицейский именно так обращается к гражданам, но никогда он не будет так обращаться к вышестоящему.

Comment: — Не могу ничем это подкрепить, — так было написано в вопросе, — где найти по данному вопросу какие-нибудь правила? Про невысокий уровень и хамство понятно. Что же с правилами?

Comment: Как раз с правилами все просто. Если Вы в обращении используется "проходим", "говорим" или что-то делаем, то предполагается совместное действие. Если Вы говорите, "садимся", то вы выражаете намерение садится вместе, если говорите "проходим", то Вы уже проходите вместе с тем, кому это говорите. Последнее , это даже не просьба , а констатация. Если Вы хотите , чтобы кто-то присел, то говорить нужно "садитесь". Если Вы имеете ввиду "проходите", а говорите "проходим", то это означает, что Вы не умеете выражать собственные мысли правильно, что и говорит о низком уровне развития. Как-то так.

Comment: Не следует (не обращаясь напрямую) употреблять Вы, — есть такое правило. Второе: вопрос о Правилах обращён был к товарищам лингвистам и филологам, он не о деликатном обращении с гражданами.